# R is saying there's already a color scale when there isn't?

Tags: r

This is truly driving me nuts. I keep getting the error "Scale for 'colour' is already present. Adding another scale for 'colour', which will replace the existing scale." but there isn't a scale for color, and it's still not replacing the color. Here is my code and the graph I'm trying to work with; I just want to change the color of my jitter plot group. However, R is telling me I'm already using a color scale. Where??
[Plot pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYR7K.png)

```
 ggplot(wf_length, aes(year_, date_diff, color = factor(cause))) +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c("red", "blue")) +
  ylim(0, 250) +
  stat_summary(fun = "mean", color = "red", size = 1, geom = "smooth") +
  ylab("Fire Length (Days)") +
  xlab("Year") +
  scale_color_discrete(name = "Cause") +
  ggtitle("Length of Fires Over Time and their Causes")
```

Answer (score 1):

you have both scale_color_manual
and scale_color_discrete.

Please choose only one. You can not choose both.
If you share a bit of data we can have a closer look

Comment: That makes more sense, but I only used that to change the name for my Cause variables. Can I use that same line to change the colors for them as well?

Edit: Yes I can! I eliminated the "discrete" color scale, and was still able to do "name = "Cause" and choose the colors of my liking with values = c(). Thank you for the second pair of eyes!